# Prove an equivalent norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, equivalence-relations

Consider $g\in C[0,1]$ a strictly positive function and bounded away from zero, prove $\|f\|_g=(\int_0^1g(x)|f(x)|^2dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is equivalent to $\|f\|=(\int_0^1f^2(x)dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

I know that I have to show $a\|f\|\leq\|f\|_g\leq b\|f\|$ for some constants $a$, $b$. But, I have some problems of computing constants $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hint: If $g$ is bounded away from $0$ and strictly positive then there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for $x \in [0,1]$, $g(x) > \varepsilon$. Also since $g$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is compact, $g$ is bounded so that there is a $K > 0$ such that $g(x) \leq K$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Try inserting those inequalities into the integral and seeing what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are there exists $c >0$ such that $c \leqslant g(x), \forall $x$, and that $g$ is continuous. Thus $g$ is also bounded above, by a constant $C$.

Thus, for every $f$ any $t \in [0,1]$
\begin{align}
c |f(t)|^2 \leqslant g(t)|f(t)|^2 \leqslant C |f(t)|^2
\end{align}
Integrating on $[0,1]$ and taking the square root answers your question.

Comment: Did you mean $ c$ $\|f\|^2$ $\leq $ $ g(x)\|f\|^2_g^2$$\leq C\|f\|^2 $ ?

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote. If you do the calculations, it shows what you're looking for. It would provide $\sqrt{c}$ and $\sqrt{C}$ as constants comparing the two norms.